# Always have 5 digits in TextBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, textbox

I need a `TextBox` in `ASP.NET MVC` such that it can only take 5 digits, not more, not less and if the number entered starts with `0`, then the value displayed in the `TextBox` is starting with a '0`.

Example,

- If I enter `12345`, the `TextBox` should display `12345`. Even if I try to enter another digit beyond the last `5`, it should not allow me to do so. Similarly, if I enter less than `5` digits, I should be prompted to enter a total of `5` digits.
- If I enter `01234`, the `TextBox` should display `01234` and not `1234`.

As I need to store in the database, exactly how it is in the `TextBox`, I have declared the field as `string`.

Comment: You can use some client side plugins to achieve this behavior. But always validate on server as well. Do not trust data coming from client.

Comment: Use a jQuery Masked TextBox control in the view to limit the input (there are plenty available), but add a `[RegularExpression]` attribute for client and server side validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `min` and `max` html attributes but they are not enforced in all the browsers so it's better to rely on Javascript/jQuery.

```js
$('.test-input').unbind('keyup change input paste').bind('keyup change input paste',function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    var val = $this.val();
    var valLength = val.length;
    var maxCount = $this.attr('max');
    if(valLength>maxCount){
        $this.val($this.val().substring(0,maxCount));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="test-input" type="number" max="5" />
```

Also, it would not be a good experience to check minimum characters validation while user is entering the value (keyup/change event), so better to check that on form submit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using an @Html.Text box in razor syntax. If so then this should work for you:

```
@Html.TextBox("FiveDigits", "", new { placeholder = "Enter 5 digits"})
```

Would go in your view, and this would go in your controller:

```
 if (TheForm["FiveDigits"] > 99999 || TheForm["FiveDigits"] < 10000 || String.IsNullorEmpty(tablename.TextHasMoreThanFiveDigits))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("TextHasMoreThanFiveDigits", "You must enter a 5 digit number");
        return View(ViewWithTextBox);
    } else { do database stuff}
```

I don't know the names of your variables so I made some up, but I have very similar logic in a program I work on

Comment: I know I might be changing the question, but can I emphasize that the contents of that `TextBox` are exactly 5 via `jQuery`>

Comment: If you use this kind of text box you can just simply add the parameter:

<input type="text" maxlength="5" id="FiveDigits" />

Comment: But we aren't specifying the minimum length here. I need it to be exactly 5. If less than 5, then add zeros to the beginning to make it 5.